# Need to bundle docker images and docker rpms with python

Tags: python, docker, compilation, docker-compose

I have a hardened RHEL system with python 2.x on it. I want a single executable that when executed will run a python script.  Packaged inside the executable would be a folder structure of rpms, images and docker-compose.  The script will yum install the rpms, load the images and run docker-compose.

I tried all day to get pyinstaller to work but it seems more tuned to creating a binary for windows and/or it assumes there is no python available on the target system.  It also leaves all the rpms and images for everyone to see and copy.

Is there a way I can just compile everything into one single executable...sort of like 'cat' everything into a .bin file and execute the .bin file?

Comment: As you've described the problem, you're looking for a virtual machine.  Tools like [Packer](https://packer.io/) can help build up VM images.  You might consider whether it's simpler to deploy your application directly into the VM without having Docker inside the VM, though there's nothing technically wrong with it otherwise.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear.  The VM is already up.  I just need to install docker and the other things I mentioned.  I am looking for a way to bundle up all of them other than the obvious tar or zip.

Answer (score 0):

I found this awesome utility that does exactly what I need.  I am able to bundle my rpms, docker images and what not into a single executable and launch them when the executable is executed.

https://github.com/megastep/makeself